# Why html5 video doesn't run in Chrome by using popcorn.js?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, popcornjs

Before adding popcorn.js, the video run great on Firefox and Chrome. Now I add popcorn.js for subtitles purpose, it work on Firefox but it does not work on Chrome(video is blank white with unclickable video control). I already have alternate video sources in HTML,

```
<video id="video" width="620" height="420" controls="true" preload="none">
    <source src="caption.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
    <source src="caption.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"' /> 
    <source src="caption.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2, H.264"' />
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video
</video>
```

Anyone tell me what wrong with it? My suspect is that popcorn.js only work on Firefox?

Comment: Strange that I keep refresh the site then go different then come back to same one, the video finally can start playing. Most of time it won't play until I keep refreshing. Still not sure why that happen

Answer (score 0):

> #### popcorn.js only work on Firefox?

#### False

Popcorn.js works great on Chrome.
Please validate the following:

1. You're using a recent version of Chrome.
2. The computer you're using is healthy (no viruses, no garbage etc...)
3. Either post the JS you wrote or go through it line by line, checking for any errors.
4. (should be 1 actually) Did you check the chrome dev tools console for any errors?